# Как обеспечить гладкое перемещение обьекта с rigidbody2D и ВКЛЮЧЕННЫМ interpolate при векторном движении одновременно с velocity? Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

У меня есть платформа, двигающаяся влево и вправо, при соприкасании с которой игрок с такой же скоростью движется влево и вправо.

Также есть коробка, которую можно как угодно двигать. Она содержит `rigidbody2D dynamic`, которая также может двигаться на платформе.

Но я столкнулся с проблемой неплавного передвижения коробки и вычитал про `interpolate` у `rigidbody2D`, но в таком случае, если она будет двигаться на платформе, то с какими-то рывками.  Такая же проблема и с игроком с включенным `interpolate`.

Как это можно исправить или сделать как-нибудь по-другому?

Answer (score 0):

Информации мало конечно (да даже кода нету) (даже сказал бы задали вопрос "почините пж" и все) но я подробно все расписывал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1539431/536087) (много же у кого на проблемы на 3D/2D физику)