# Объекты проходят друг сквозь друга

Tags: c#, unity3d, 3d

Начинаю потихоньку осваивать юнити (по гайдам с ютуба конечно же). Делаю простенькую головоломку с кубами. Цель - вытащить красный куб.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На всех кубах висит `Rigidbody` и `Box Collider` с материалом с нулевым трением.

Проблема же заключается в том что при упоре трех или более кубов одного типа в другой они просто проталкиваются сквозь него, даже без предварительного разгона. При том, если кубов меньше трех, все работает более-менее нормально, хотя попытки пролезть все-таки предпринимают)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если в это время еще и двигать голубой блок, то произойдет это xD
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выглядит забавно, но вести себя так они не должны. Пробовал менять у `Rigidbody` `Interpolate` и `Collision Detection`, эффекта никакого.

Погуглил, ответа не нашел (Скорее всего плохо гуглил)

Бонусом еще вопросик: как сделать чтобы кубы не цеплялись углами при движении? На сцене вроде расставляю все ровно, `Freeze Rotation` и `Freeze Position` выставлены, но все равно умудряются врезаться друг в друга. Пока что просто уменьшил коллайдеры у префабов с 1 на 0.99, но работает ненадежно и выглядит кривовато.

Скрипт прилагаю, он на все кубы один:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class CubeMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] KeyCode moveForwardKey;
    [SerializeField] KeyCode moveBackKey;
    [SerializeField] Vector3 moveDirection;

    private AudioSource audioSource;

    private Rigidbody rb;

    public static event Action OnTrigger;
    void Start()
    {
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(moveForwardKey))
        {
            rb.velocity += moveDirection;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(moveBackKey))
        {
            rb.velocity -= moveDirection;
        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(this.CompareTag("Player") && other.CompareTag("Finish"))
        {
            if (OnTrigger != null)
            {
                OnTrigger.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        audioSource.Play();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/936026/373567 может быть полезно.

Comment: зачем здесь физика? твое поле - сетка 10x10 (условно) кубы могут занимать 1/несколько ячеек на этой сетке. перед тем, как сдвинуть куб, проверяешь какие клетки у него на пути не заняты и двигаешь его туда хоть через transform.position, хоть через DOTween анимацией какой-нибудь

Comment: @KOTlK Через физику оно как-то проще, смотрится лучше и возможностей побольше. В этом уровне, например, планировалось толкать красный куб к выходу с помощью зеленого, т.к красный самостоятельно может двигаться только по Z но, в отличие от синих, ось X у него не заморожена

Comment: @PelemeniuM, с физикой не бывает просто, никогда, от слова "совсем", поведение не предсказуемо, это не возможности, это геморой и проблемы. Ни в одной игре этого типа, что ты видил физика не используется!!! Выхлядит это... никак, ничего хорошего.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас каждый раз происходит ДОБАВЛЕНИЕ скорости, то есть если долго ждать она станет ОЧЕНЬ большой и так как синий объект не будет успевать выкидывать зеленый объект то он просто пройдет до конца а подлетает он изза того что когда он на краю то выталкивает вверх потому что внизу занято а объект зашел на всю высоту и остается только вверх

Прочитал пост в самом низу в "Связанное" и да, там есть правильне движение с AddForce так думаю будет работать

Кстати если все делать с AddForce то и сдвиг объектов должен починиться так как по факту он упрется изза физики а с просто добавлением направление он заходит в блок, блок хочет вытолкнуть его и немного смещает

Я думаю что весь изначальный скрипт выглядит ненадежно там очень много багов:

- AudioSource может отсутствовать
- Rigidbody может отсутствовать
- Каждый куб проверяет кнопку
- Позиция может быть указанна не правильная например (0, -1, 0) или (57, 0, 0) (у меня конечно тоже можно такое указать но с AddForce это просто будет скорость больше и он не пролетит (не уверен, не проверял))
- Проверка по тегам тупо (допустимо для двух трех объектов но там по факту для всех кубов (даже если ПОЧТИ никогда не прикасаются к финишу то зачем их вообще тогда обрабатывать))
- Ну и как раз баг с проходом кубов через друг друга, нужно использовать метод

Снизу есть весь измененный код и обычный просто с починенным движением (возможно)

Default:
Предполагаю что так как вы прибавляете скорость напрямую а не через метод то происходит такая хрень
Попробуйте AddForce у него две перегрузки
[Подробнее](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html)

```
AddForce(Vector3 force, ForceMode mode=ForceMode.Force) {}
AddForce(float x, float y, float z, ForceMode mode=ForceMode.Force) {}
```

ForceMode имеет значения:

- ForceMode.Force
- ForceMode.Acceleration
- ForceMode.Impulse
- ForceMode.VelocityChange

Предлагаю такой код (я также добавил некоторые незначительнве изменения наример: добавил модификаторы доступа)

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class CubeMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private KeyCode MoveForwardKey;
    [SerializeField] private KeyCode MoveBackKey;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 MoveDirection;

    private AudioSource _AudioSource;

    private Rigidbody _RigidBody;

    public static event Action OnTrigger;

    private void Start()
    {
        _AudioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        _RigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(MoveForwardKey))
        {
            _RigidBody.AddForce(MoveDirection);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(MoveBackKey))
        {
            _RigidBody.AddForce(MoveDirection * -1);
        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider Other)
    {
        if(this.CompareTag("Player") && other.CompareTag("Finish"))
        {
            if (OnTrigger != null)
            {
                OnTrigger.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision Collision)
    {
        _AudioSource.Play();
    }
}
```

Список изменений:

- Изменил способы передвижения
- Добавил модификаторы доступа
- Переименовал поля по нотации C# (приватные поля (с _), аргументы методов, переменные должны быть в стиле camelCase а не PascalCase но я придерживаюсь такому стилю так что вы можете изменить обратно)

А также я бы советовал разделить отвественность этого скрипта (он делает слишком много и тем более каждый куб отслеживвает клавишу) а еще не советую делать проверку по тегу, еще в событие лучше передавать объект столкновения и вместо проверки на null можно сделать OnTrigger?.Invoke()
Вот как я предлогаю разделить:

Player.cs - вешается на игрока:

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource AudioSource; // Если хотите звуки от всех объектов то переносите отсюда в куб и убираете SerializeField а к кубу добавляете [RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]

    public static delegate void FinishedAction();
    public static event FinishedAction Finished;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider Other) {
        if (Other.gameObject.getType() == typeof(Finish)) {
            Finished?.Invoke();
        }
    }

    // Если хотите звуки от всех объектов то переносите этот код в куб
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision Other) {
        AudioSource.Play();
    }
}
```

Cube.cs - вешается на все кубы и игрока:

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class Cube : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private KeyController KeyController;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 MoveDirection;

    private Rigidbody _RigidBody;

    private void Start()
    {
        _RigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        KeyController.KeyPressed += (Direction Direction) => {
            if (Direction == KeyController.Direction.Forward)
            {
                _RigidBody.AddForce(MoveDirection);
            }
            else
            {
                _RigidBody.AddForce(MoveDirection * -1);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Finish.cs - вешается на финиш:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Finish : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Если хотите реализуйте дополнительную логику
}
```

KeyController.cs - вешается на один объект на сцене например на пустой объект (также можно написать Singleton (этот шаблон гарантирует что экземпляр класса будет только 1 (PS: я пересмотрел вопрос и понял что их может быть несколько для разных движений так что хорошо что еще и на Singleton время не потратил) (со всеми загрузками поверх сцен (не помню как назвается но там можно сделать что при выгрузке сцены скрипт останется и перейдет на другую) удаление дубликатов и тд) но я не буду)

```
using UnityEngine;

public class KeyController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private KeyCode MoveForwardKey;
    [SerializeField] private KeyCode MoveBackwardKey;

    public enum Direction
    {
        Forward,
        Backward
    }

    public static delegate void KeyPressedAction(Direction Direction);
    public static event KeyPressedAction KeyPressed;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(MoveForwardKey))
        {
            KeyPressed?.Invoke(Direction.Forward);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(MoveBackwardKey))
        {
            KeyPressed?.Invoke(Direction.Backward);
        }
    }
}
```

Надеюсь я помог, в любом случае пожалуйста добавьте модификаторы доступа также если используете второй вариант (да и первый тоже) то добавьте пространство имен)

Пример:

```
using MyNamespace1;
using MyNamespace1.Class1;

namespace MyNamespace2
{
    // Content
}
```

Возможны ошибки так как писать код на сайте неудобно а также нету возможности проверить (и где то могут отсутствовать точки с запятыми так как сервер на питоне писал долго и отвык от c#)

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: На будущее, если вам не хочется тратить время, не делайте этого, но не следует по несколько раз в ответе об этом писать. Каждый написанный ответ может быть проигнорирован автором вопроса, даже если он идеальный и большой, это нормально, помните об этом, когда начинаете писать новый ответ.

Comment: в любом случае я могу сам использовать этот код тут считай всë движение написанно и только скрипты для меню нужны и всего такого

Comment: Спасибо, что указали на ошибки, но основная проблема никуда не делась. Они только стали смешнее разлетаться). Думаю можно попробовать просто останавливать движение при упоре одного куба в другой. Вопрос - как это сделать? Я могу конечно налепить с двух сторон два пустых объекта и останавливать когда они соприкасаются с другим кубом, но думаю это можно реализовать как-то проще.

Comment: я сейчас создам такую же игру и попробую починить если будут проблемы а если не будет то прикрепите картинки вывода в консоль и также настройки на кубах (инспектор)

Comment: не нужно ничего лепить я кажется нашел причину (произвел несколько замеров с velocity +/- и с AddForce ну и впринципе почти разницы нету в поведение между ними а так насчет починки проскакивания в блоки поменяйте с discrete на какой нибудь другой и также поставьте Interpolate None я провел около 20 замеров с разными действиями (например я выяснил что блок на который на один конец сбрасывают кубик с массой 100 а на второй с массой 1 ведет себя по самому адекватному при Collision Detection Continuos Dynamic) и вы впринципе можете просто поставить как я сказал либо почитать документацию

Comment: Я попробовал еще поиграться со значениями и вышло, что при массе 5 и скорости 125 кубы ведут себя адекватно. Раньше было 1 и 55 соответственно. При старых значениях оно как-то странно работало: При движении двух зеленых кубов в синий они просто упираются и стоят, но как только подключается третий все разом взлетают. Также заметил что если масса синего например 2, а зеленых 1, то все нормально. Но работает это только в одну сторону - синие сквозь зеленых проходят спокойно. В любом случае теперь все работает как надо. Но все равно спасибо, не думал что кто-то будет так заморачиваться)